# I want a frozen copy of AngularFire t Obsersable

Tags: typescript, promise, observable, angularfire, angularfire2

Okay, let met explain. I am getting a obsersable from AngularFire Database, and here is what I pretend to do:
- get 2 static copies of the obsersable response
- show 1 static copy
- allow user to modify this static copy and not save it
- when user decides too cancel the changes, i simply get the copy number 2 and set it to copy number 1.

getting obsersable:

```
this.afoDatabase.object("usuarios/"+this.userKey+"/pacientes/"+this.pacienteKey).map(res=> {
  this.model = res;
  this.model2 = res;
}).first().toPromise();
```

when the users decides to cancel the changes, here is what i am doing:

```
this.model = this.model2;
  // this.model is the copy number 1 and this.model2 is the 'unchanged' copy number 2
```

but when i do it, the copy number 2, even that i never showed  or changed it, is exactly equal to copy number 1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated**

You can use [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) like

```
let supplier = this.afoDatabase.object("usuarios/" + this.userKey + "/pacientes/" + this.pacienteKey);
Observable.combineLatest(supplier, supplier)
  .map([model1, model2]=> {
    this.model1=model1;
    this.model2=model2;
  }).first()
  ...
```

CombineLatest will emit an array when both of these observables emits. Here `model1` and `model2` should have same value.

*Note*: This will create two separate requests. If you want to create single request then look below at Previous Answer.

**Previous Answer**

Look here

```js
let res = {foo:1,bar:2}
let model1 = res;
let model2 = res;
model1.foo=3;
console.log(model1.foo) //3
console.log(model2.foo) //3
```

Because when we declare `model1` and `model2` with value `res`, so both points to the same object. Both holds the reference of same object (here `res`) and changing one changes other.

What you need to do is clone `res` to `model2` so it will a different object with same value as `res`. Cloning is of two types shallow and deep.

1. [Efficient deep copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
2. [Shallow copy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)
3. [Difference between shallow and deep copy.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy)

If your `res` objects values are string, numbers etc then you need shallow copy. Example

```
res= {a:1,b:"2"}
```

If they contains array, other objects then you need deep copy. Example

```
res={a:{c:1},b:[2,3]}
```

Comment: Thank you! Instead of a assign the "res" to the models, i simply assigned a copy of it, using the assign method explained on this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Answer (score 0):

Map is used to modify data received in each event.
So you need to assign data to model like

```
.first((data) => model = data)
```

Then use

```
.subscribe((data) => model2 = data)
```

If you want to modify data format you may call

```
.map((data) => { let res = modifyData(data); return res});
```

Update:

```
import { timer } from 'rxjs/observable/timer';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';

let model, model1;

let observable = timer(0, 1000);

observable.first().subscribe((n) => { 
  model = n;
});

observable.subscribe((n) => {
  model1 = n;
});
```

Comment: .looks like it is not how use the first() method. Here what it returns:: Argument of type '(data: void) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: void, index: number, source: Observable<void>) => boolean'